# Use JSM Serializer to serialise to JSON 'primitives'

Tags: php, jms-serializer

Perhaps I am going at it in the wrong way, but I would like to be able to serialise an object (which represents a primitive) into JSON 'primitives'. With the help of JsonSerializable Interface and json_encode that is easy  but I would like to be able to generalise this with help of JSM Serializer.

I played with the inline annotation, but whatever I try it seems when serialising an object an string representing of an object is mandatory? Is this correct? How would I be able to do this if possible?

```
class ATest implements SingularValueObjectInterface, JsonSerializable
{
    /**
     * @JMS\Accessor(getter="get",setter="set")
     */
    private $value = 45;

    /**
     * @return string
     * @JMS\Inline
     */
    public function get()
    {
        return $this->value * $this->value;
    }

    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return $this->get();
    }

}

$serializer = \JMS\Serializer\SerializerBuilder::create()->build();
$a          = new ATest();



var_dump(json_encode($a), $serializer->serialize($a, 'json'));

string(4) "2025" <- I want this.
vs
"{"value":2025}"
```

I have more complex objects too representing arrays/collections for example

Comment: Did you ever find out how to solve this scenario and would be able to reply  here with the solution?

Comment: no sorry, moved away from JMS